how to solve x11 error in multithreaded R
I have been getting X11 error like below when I use foreach multithreading, and in the threads I'm doing some plots and save them as png with ggplot(), png() and dev.off() calls:
Error in { :
task 2 failed - "X11 fatal IO error: please save work and shut down R"
I have tried a number of ways to solve it but none of them work:

used flock::lock & flock::unlock around those plot related calls to avoid contention, adding sleep for couple of seconds after unlock just to be extra cautious
used png(..., type="cairo") (verified capabilities("cairo") returns true)
make a Rcpp function that wrap around and call XInitThreads() and all it first thing in the script

None of it seems to solve the problem - any suggestion?

One might be able to fix this by using multiprocessing instead of multithreading.

well my main reason of using multi thread here is there is a large data set loaded into memory and it can be read/shared among worker threads with low overhead - if i want to go the route of multiprocessing i'd need to look at using shared memory in R... which is not something i want to go down the path with

Alright, you don't wanna use e.g. redis. R plot devices don't seem to be thread safe. If you are using ggplot2, you can use ggsave directly, see here

@danlooo switched to ggsave but still the same:
Error in { :
task 13 failed - "X11 fatal IO error: please save work and shut down R"
8: stop(simpleError(msg, call = expr))
7: e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data)
6: foreach(task = iter(task_table[!(task_id %in% done_task_id)],
...

[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
R: xcb_io.c:263: poll_for_event: Assertion !xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)


ok. But this is hard to debug outside your environment.
